# US date format stuck on me on ms access

Tags: sql-server, forms, vba, date

I use the following code to add, edit data in table with form. All works fine, but there is one field which is in date format. I choose the date in the form with date pick up window, but when it imports it to the table it changes the date format from the UK date format to US.

For example I choose `01/11/2014` (1-nov-2014) in the date pick up window in form, and when I add the records to the table, (what I can see in the subform too) it shows `11/01/2014` (11-jan-2014). When I edit the same record with same form it still shows the `11/01/2014`. So basically it changes the day and the month.

I've tried to put like `29/11/2014` then it didn't swap the day and the month. I've checked the region setting in control panel, it shows `UK`, I've tried to make format in my subform, I added the `mm-dd-yyyy` format to sql, but non of them helped.

Any idea how could I set this?

Thanks for any help

```
Option Compare Database

Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()
If Me.txtName.Tag & "" = "" Then
        CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO [import]([product name], [QtyImport], [ImportDate])" & _
        " VALUES('" & Me.txtName & "'," & Me.txtOrderedQty & ",#" & Me.txtDate & "#)"

    Else
        CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE import " & _
        " SET [product name] = '" & Me.txtName & "'" & _
        ", [QtyImport] = " & Me.txtOrderedQty & "" & _
        ", [ImportDate] = #" & Me.txtDate & "#" & _
        " WHERE [product name] = '" & Me.txtName.Tag & "'"
    End If

    cmdClear_Click
    importSubform.Form.Requery
End Sub

Private Sub cmdClear_Click()
    Me.txtName = ""
    Me.txtOrderedQty = ""
    Me.txtDate = ""

    Me.txtName.SetFocus
    Me.CmdEdit.Enabled = True
    Me.CmdAdd.Caption = "Add"
    Me.txtName.Tag = ""
End Sub

Private Sub CmdEdit_Click()
  If Not (Me.importSubform.Form.Recordset.EOF And Me.importSubform.Form.Recordset.BOF) Then
        With Me.importSubform.Form.Recordset
            Me.txtName = .Fields("product name")
            Me.txtOrderedQty = .Fields("QtyImport")
            Me.txtDate = .Fields("ImportDate")

            Me.txtName.Tag = .Fields("Product Name")
            Me.CmdAdd.Caption = "Update"
            Me.CmdEdit.Enabled = False
        End With
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub cmdExit_Click()
    DoCmd.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: Stop concatenating your SQL as a string, and use parameterized queries. Then you can just assign a DateTime to the parameter and let the database format it properly, instead of dealing with this sort of conversion issue. It also avoids SQL injection. There are dozens of posts here dealing with parameterized queries, if you search for them.

Answer (score 1):

First parse the inputed date value to a datetime object then pass it's value to DB.
While binding again get the datetime object from the value in database then parse it to get value in 'dd-mm-yy' format.

Alternatively, you can also use the convert method to get date object from your inputed date value which is in 'dd-mm-yy' format i.e.

```
convert(date, @inputed, 103)
```

It will give date object where @inputed is your inputed date value.

Then store it in database and while displaying it again convert it back to 'dd-mm-yy' format using the following function.

```
convert(varchar, @savedDate, 103)
```

This line will be modified as follows:

```
CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO [import]([product name], [QtyImport], [ImportDate])" & _
        " VALUES('" & Me.txtName & "'," & Me.txtOrderedQty & ",convert(date, '" & Me.txtDate & "',103)"
```

I hope this above line is correct, correct if wrong as I work i, in C#.

Comment: Hi It looks good, but I have no idea how exactly I should use it. In my VBA ode for example, how could I put this convert method ? And also where shall i include and how this convert varchar function? thank you

Comment: hi, did it helped you? or you are still facing some issue

Comment: unfortunately it didn't help, it's just not in the right format or I have a feeling that I should just set somewhere in windows or Microsoft Office the right date format but I can't find where... :/ soo annoying!

Answer (score 1):

OK So finally I found out how to format date in VBA. I've changed the "values" line in the cmd add click to the following :

```
" VALUES('" & Me.txtName & "'," & Me.txtOrderedQty & ",#" & Format(Me.txtDate, "mm/dd/yyyy") & "#)"
```

So this is the code what is actually working to keep everything in UK date format, bcs I read somewhere that VBA always use US date format, no matter u have set your region etc..